# Getting data from a csv file to a sqlplus table -> getting this data from sqlplus table to html table skeleton

Tags: java, jquery, sqlplus, oracle12c, sql-loader

I am a newbie in programming, so please excuse me if some of the stuff I say sounds stupid or not to the point. I am trying to explain what I have to do as best as I understand. I am looking forward to having guidance from all, and hope it solves my problem.

So the steps which I believe I have to undertake is as follows:

1. I have a CSV file and I have to load data from CSV file into the SQLPLUS table. The file has 17 columns. Now here comes the tricky part, there is one column which has values which correspond to my column number 2 in different rows. For examples, lets say the cell first row of second column is "FRUIT" and the FIRST SECOND and THIRD row of the 14th column are APPLE, MANGO and ORANGE. all three correspond to the fruit so must be shown in the same row when displaying in the html table.
2. I want to know, how should I configure my control file so that the apple mangoes and oranges must come in the same row as fruits.
3. I dont want it just for the display purpose because after this is done, I have to retrieve info from the the (apple orange mango column) for the current row and display it as 3 radio buttons.

I am not sure how well I explained it. But please if anyone has any idea please let me know.

This is a sample table:
double quotes mean one row. so its basically fruits then null below and null below.

```
"|FRUITS|APPLES|"
"| NULL |ORANGES|"
"| NULL |MANGOES|"
```

What I want to implement is:

```
|FRUITS|APPLES,ORANGES,MANGOES(displayed one below the other)|
```

then take the information from the cell in which apples oranges and mangoes are displayed and display it as dropdown selector.

THANKS>.

What I have tried is uploading the csv through sqloader using the str x0d . It displays the fruits in the same row as fruit, however when I am getting the data from the current cell, I cannot extract apples oranges and mangoes separately.

What I believe is I have to introduce some delimiter and then segregate based on that delimiter.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the result you want.  You say you want the values "displayed one below the other".  Does that mean you want them to be three rows of data in your table?  Or do you want a single row of data in the table with a comma-separated list as the value?  If the latter, I'm not sure what one below the other would refer to

Comment: Hello Justin, I want them to be displayed in a single row, however with line breaks.